# Problem with working TensorFlow graph and Keras model in multithreaded env

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

Hello guys I am working on a project where I am creating two threads.
!. one for capturing images from ipcam using cv2 and adding those images to deque with maxlen 10
2. here I am converting deque to list and predicting using model on it. basically I am using two models one for extracting features and anther will predict on those features. 
Here's the sample code

```
 def window(deque):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.42.129:8080/video')      

    frame_seq = 10
        # model = load_model('models/model_seq_' + str(frame_seq) + '.h5')
        while(True):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
                print(" orking or not")
                # print( " frame type --", frame.shape)
                frame_que.append(frame)
            else:
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

def predictor(deque, model):

while True:
    frames = list(deque)
    outputs = []
    with tf.Session() as Sess:
        tf_model = object.load_model('101', Sess)
        for frame in frames:
        outputs.append(tf_model.decode(frame))
   pred = model.predict(outputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = load_model(path)
    deque = collections.deque()
    window = threading.Thread(target=window, args=(frame_que,))
    predictor = threading.Thread(target=predictor, args=(frame_que , model))
    window.start()
    predictor.start()
```

the problem is after the first iteration of inner for loop of predictor the thread window stops
and does not capture new frames from ipcam

Code is not systematically intended.

Comment: Can you post an error? Maybe add a `try` in the thread to catch the failure.
A few month ago I had an similar issue with keras in a multithreaded environment and I fix it with [this](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1728728) way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. actually that is a problem there is no error. thread window just stops working. I will try to add try in thread windows.